# How rare is a picksaw

Tags: terraria-console

I've fought 6 golems and I didn't get a single picksaw

How rare is a picksaw? I know they all have the same rarity but is it pure luck to get it or the game hates me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Picksaw) the Picksaw has roughly a 1 in 8 chance of dropping from The Golem.

While this means that you should expect it to drop within **8** attempts, probability doesn't guarantee it.

It is pure luck, and unfortunately, this means it could take more than 8 attempts. Keep at it, and it should drop within the next couple of true.

Answer (score 1):

[12.5% chance of dropping from the Golem](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Picksaw). The game doesn't hate you.